Selenium in an online notebook like kaggle
Can anyone tell me if it's possible to run a selenium script on Kaggle? I need to scrape data from a website. To automate a task.
If yes, how?
I need need the scraped data to keep updated on a csv list. I already know I can schedule to program to keep running automatically on kaggle at a specific time interval.

Yes, It is possible.
Install Dependencies for Chrome and selenium
!apt-get update -y
!apt-get install -y \
libglib2.0-0 \
libnss3 \
libdbus-glib-1-2 \
libgconf-2-4 \
libfontconfig1 \
libvulkan1 \
gconf2-common \
libwayland-server0 \
libgbm1 \
udev \
libu2f-udev 
!apt --fix-broken install -y  

Download and extract Chrome
!wget -P /tmp https://edgedl.me.gvt1.com/edgedl/chrome/chrome-for-testing/116.0.5845.96/linux64/chrome-linux64.zip
!unzip /tmp/chrome-linux64.zip -d /usr/bin/

Download and extract Chromedriver:
!wget -P /tmp https://edgedl.me.gvt1.com/edgedl/chrome/chrome-for-testing/116.0.5845.96/linux64/chromedriver-linux64.zip
!unzip /tmp/chromedriver-linux64.zip -d /usr/bin/

Install Python libraries
!apt install -y python3-selenium
!pip install selenium==3.141.0

Import the libraries, configure and start using, refer here for more details.

Ty for this answer
